# don't change mouse icon when hovering over a marker

Tags: javascript, css, leaflet

I have a map with a number of markers. When a user clicks on one marker information for that marker is displayed on a side pane. To accomplish that I have added 'click' listeners to the markers and also store marker identifiers more or less as suggested in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31732215/uniquely-identifying-leaflet-markers).

Now, on certain modes I don't want the markers to be clickable (but still want them to appear on the screen). It is easy for me to remove all the 'click' listeners. However, when I hover over them with my mouse, the icon does change from the "open palm" to the "pointed hand" confusing the user. Upon investigating I see that the canvas class normally has the `leaflet-zoom-animated` class, but when I hover over a marker, the `leaflet-interactive` class gets added. I can change that cursor using, e.g.:

```
.leaflet-interactive {
    cursor: crosshair !important;
}
```

... but this has two problems:

1. it's not something I can toggle on and off depending on the various user interaction modes my application finds itself in
2. it's still jarring because the cursor does change and, further, I can't change it to the open palm cursor that Leaflet is normally using, since that's a non-default cursor and it's not clear to me how to access it.

Comment: Can you please add a code snippet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can remove the click listener, I suppose that you can also add a css class to your marker. Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/Mossart/w9830at1/7/ (look at the top marker)

```
var breakside = [45.571601194035345, -122.65673562884331];
var marker1 = L.marker(breakside).addTo(map);
marker1._icon.classList.add("not-clickable");
```

CSS:

```
.not-clickable {
  cursor: grab;
}
```

Comment: I've verified this and it works. Unfortunately, this doesn't help with other `L.circleMarker` objects which don't have an `_icon` property.

Comment: With a circleMarker you can update the option `className` https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#circlemarker-classname

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working. I create normal `L.circleMarker` objects, set the `className` property on them using m.className = 'not-clickable' but the class is not reflected on the `path` DOM elements that correspond to each `L.circleMarker`. I 've tried using both a canvas and a non-canvas renderer.

Comment: ok, so I think I found another method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60642381/274677

Answer (score 1):

This works for `L.circleMarker` objects on a canvas renderer:

```
marker.options.interactive = false;
```

Curiously, it doesn't work on a non-canvas renderer.